# Computing time between two dates and returning number of days

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Given two columns in a dataframe that are date time objects:

Checkin                Checkout
2018-09-13 19:55:00    2018-09-16 13:08:00

I'd like to compute the time difference in days and have it output as an integer to a new column. So far, I've done this but the output also includes seconds.

```
delta = df['Checkin'] - df['Checkout']
print(delta)
```

The output however ends up being:

2 days 17:13:00

and is output as a DT object. I'd like it to just output as `2` and as an integer in a new column.

How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need **[`dt.days`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.days.html)**

```
(df['checkin'] - df['checkout']).dt.days
```

Output:

```
0   -3
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Ah.. That was simple... Thanks.